# UIPickerView button selector issue in iOS 7

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios7, uipickerview

Having a weird issue of UIPickerView only on iOS 7

I have a UIPickerView which contains 3 rows. Each row has a button whose selector is defined, but it never respond on button tap.

Here is my code.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component
       reusingView:(UIView *)view {

NSLog(@"row %d", row);

if(view == nil) {
    view = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
}

[view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIButton *manageButton = (UIButton *)[view viewWithTag:TAG_MANAGE + row];
UILabel *descTypeLabel = (UILabel *) [view viewWithTag:TAG_DESCTYPE_LABEL + row];
if(manageButton == nil &&  row != 0) {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(210, 7, 90, 30);
    manageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    manageButton.frame = frame;
    [manageButton setTitle:@"Manage" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [manageButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [manageButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"blackButton.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    manageButton.tag = TAG_MANAGE + row;
    [view addSubview:manageButton];
}
if(descTypeLabel == Nil) {
    descTypeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 190, 44)];
    descTypeLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    descTypeLabel.tag = TAG_DESCTYPE_LABEL + row;
    [descTypeLabel setText:[descTypes objectAtIndex:row]];
    [view addSubview:descTypeLabel];
    [descTypeLabel release];
}
//[manageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(managePressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[manageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(manageButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

return view;
}

-(void) manageButtonPressed : (UIButton *) sender {
//Not Called
}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution for the same? I am also facings similar issue.

Comment: You can't place a button on picker view row. So i have added a toolbar above it and place the button on. I use the row number to perform desired functionality through selector

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't use button on picker view cell. I have used toolbar and added a bar button item on it. By this

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

you will get the row number and use that to perform desired functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

instead in iOS 7 and do your needed work in it.

Comment: The user wants action on the Button in the picker cell and not on entire picker cell.

Comment: Prior to iOS 7 this does fairly well. For a UIButton in each row of a UIPickerView, the button tap actions are available. But in iOS 7 this do not work and one needs to use didSelectRow instead and figure out which row/button is tapped via viewForRow method of UIPickerView. You can give it a try in iOS 7/XCode 5 [stable version]