# UIButton addTarget doesn't work with iOS7,but works in IOS6

Tags: ios, ios7, uibutton, uipickerview

Obviously, this code works in iOS 6. By the way, it has problem in iOS 7.

I add UIButton to every row in a UIPickerView:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIButton *btnRow=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [btnRow addTarget:self action:@selector(touch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btnRow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30);
    int tag= selfTextField.tag/10000 - 1;
    [btnRow setTitle:[[pickerArray objectAtIndex:tag] objectAtIndex:row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    return btnRow;
}
```

Comment: EDIT: DUPLICATE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266966/uibutton-addtarget-doesnt-work-with-ios7

Comment: This is a better duplicate though no real answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245744/pickerview-button-selector-issue-in-ios-7.  Why not use a table view instead?

Comment: where is your addSubview:btnRow method?

Comment: Some UITextFields should be picked by user,including some date.So,I use UIDatePicker and UIPickerView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't place a button on picker view row. So i have added a toolbar above UIPickerView and added a bar button item on it. I use the row number to perform desired functionality through selector

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
     ....
     //get the row number & Perform desired functionality
     ....
}
```

you will get the row number and use that to perform desired functionality.

Comment: But it works in IOS6.I just want to know what causes the problem.

Comment: The desired functionality signs the selected row and shows the selected row's content in a UITextFied. So,the delegate function can't solve my problem.What's more,how can You add the toolbar above UIPickerView and keep the UIPickerView work normally.Add toolbar on every row?